# what is wrong with .this. javascript if else code?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

it works if i use the first half only but i need to widen the parameters

```
//document.querySelectorAll('font[color="black"]');
var fonts = document.querySelectorAll('font[color="black"]');
var searchString = 'Mir';
var searchString2 = 'MirrorCreator';
for (var i = 0; i < fonts.length; i++) {
  var font = fonts[i];
  if (fonts[i].innerHTML.indexOf(searchString) !== - 1) {
    //alert('Match');
    var eventLink = 'ComeHere';
    var elA = document.createElement('a');
    elA.setAttribute('id', eventLink);
    elA.setAttribute('name', eventLink);
    font.appendChild(elA);
    window.location.hash = 'ComeHere';
    break;
  } 
  else (fonts[i].innerHTML.indexOf(searchString2) !== - 1) {
    //alert('Match');
    var eventLink2 = 'ComeHere2';
    var elA2 = document.createElement('a');
    elA2.setAttribute('id', eventLink2);
    elA2.setAttribute('name', eventLink2);
    font.appendChild(elA2);
    window.location.hash = 'ComeHere2';
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you traing to do? and What's the problem with the code?

Comment: Instead of dumbing your code, please explain what is wrong and what you want to achieve. Also post possible error messages!

Comment: instead of using `else` use `else if`, this will make your else block operational.

Comment: i got the answer from down here thanks for you all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you have wrong syntax:

```
else (fonts[i].innerHTML.indexOf(searchString2) !== - 1) {
```

It should be simple

```
else {
```

or

```
else if (fonts[i].innerHTML.indexOf(searchString2) !== - 1) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your if else statement.

```
if(// conditional)
{
// do something.
}
else if(// conditional){
// do something....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `else` needs to be `else if`, because `else` isn't expecting `(fonts[i].innerHTML.indexOf(searchString2) !== - 1)`